How could I change file creation/modification date by numerical filename order?
I have a bunch of pictures that are named by numerical order (i.e. file 1.jpg, file 2.jpg, file 3.jpg, etc) but when moved to my secure photo vault app, I am only able to sort by date created and date added and so it displays the photos out of order. How can I change the file creation/modification date of these pictures such that 'file 1.jpg' was created/modified at a date sooner then the next? That way, when sorted by date created, the photos will appear in numerical order. Note: I am on Windows 10.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
